# Disable hibernate until next reboot

Tags: systemd, nixos, surface

I have a dedicated GPU on my laptop (Microsoft Surface Book 1) which is running nixos, with systemd. The GPU is detachable and power management is a bit of a mess. So I have a script that awakens the GPU if I need it for some application. However, when the GPU is turned on, hibernate stops working. I really don't want to deal with this issue. Is there a way to disable hibernate until the next full system restart?